# What is a "dimension snapshot" in a functional data engineering approach to deal with slowly changing dimensions?

Tags: database, postgresql, functional-programming, etl, airflow

As mentioned by Maxime Beauchemin in his popular post [Functional Data Engineering — a modern paradigm for batch data processing](https://medium.com/@maximebeauchemin/functional-data-engineering-a-modern-paradigm-for-batch-data-processing-2327ec32c42a), Maxime recommends dealing with slowly changing dimensions by taking dimension snapshots where a new partition is appended at each ETL schedule.

> But how do we model this in a functional data warehouse without mutating data?
>   Simple. With dimension snapshots where a new partition is appended at each ETL schedule. The dimension table becomes a collection of dimension snapshots where each partition contains the full dimension as-of a point in time.

I tried to dig in the comments for an answer but could not find a simple explanation. What is meant here by taking a snapshot of the dimension and appending it to the daily partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A snapshot is a table value that was the value of some base/variable table as of some time/version. Here "dimension snapshot" seems to mean "dimension table snapshot". The author seems to suggest a new regime whose dimension table is like the old one with an added time/version column/dimension on which they partition. Under the old regime we make updates to the dimension table, at certain times, each a version. Under the new regime each time/version we would have updated the old dimension table to some new state we instead take (a snapshot of) that state, add the new column set to the time/version, and add those rows to the new dimension table.

Ask the author, it's a recent blog.

Answer (score 0):

This presentation from Maxime might help clarifying the concept and approach suggested. It contains an actual example:
https://youtu.be/4Spo2QRTz1k?t=952

TLDW/R; The approach is whenever you build dimension tables you store the whole output of that (instead of say updating an existing table). You add some kind of time-based partition column (for instance `as_of_date` which translates into something like `dimensions/customer/as_of_date=20210726/*` in terms of storage) if you don't have that already in your model so that you can query all those dimension snapshots